# Combining values in nested objects with common properties

Tags: javascript, object, nested

### # Problem

Hello. I have a JSON response containing a varying amount of objects (a set of indicators), each containing a fixed set of other objects (geometries) that each contain properties (one of which is 'score').

I'm trying to gather these 'score' properties in order to later do stuff such as min/mean/max by geometry.

### # Sample

Here's an example (keeping in mind there could be more than two indicators):

```
let data = [   {
    {
      "indicator": "A",
      "geom": "1",
      "score": 1
    },
    {
      "indicator": "A",
      "geom": "2",
      "score": 2
    }   },   {
    {
      "indicator": "B",
      "geom": "1",
      "score": 3
    },
    {
      "indicator": "B",
      "geom": "2",
      "score": 4
    }   } ]
```

### # Expected result

The result I'm looking for would be something like this, with concatenated values originating from different sub-objects :

```
let expectedResult =   {
      {
      "indicator": ["A", "B"],
      "geom": "1",
      "score": [1,3]
    },
    {
      "indicator": ["A", "B],
      "geom": "2",
      "score": [2,4]
    }   }
```

### # My (no good) solution

My current, ugly buggy solution is to create an array with all geom ids :

```
let id = data[0].map(obj => obj.geom);
```

Then get a complete list of all key-value :

```
let keyval;
data.map((indic) => { indic.map((geom) => 
    { keyval.push([car.geom, car.score])})});
```

And finally combine geom id var with values that have identical id (and slice off the redundant id) :

```
    id.map((geom, idx) => {keyval.map((arr) => {
            if (car === arr[0]) { id.push(geom, arr.splice(0,1)})
            }
        })
    });
```

Would anyone know of a more elegant/efficient.. and more importantly working solution ? During my research saw a lot of `Array.prototype.reduce()`, but didn't figure out how to use it in such a nested configuration.

Thanks,
O.

Comment: Are you trying to parse based on geom? If so, would something like:
geoms = {
 1: [     
        { "indicator": "A", "geom": "1", "score": 1 },
        { "indicator": "B", "geom": "1", "score": 2 },
 ],
 2: [
        { "indicator": "A", "geom": "2", "score": 1 },
        { "indicator": "B", "geom": "2", "score": 2 },
  ],
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) to collect the values into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), then use [Map#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to convert back to an array:

```js
const data = [[{"indicator":"A","geom":"1","score":1},{"indicator":"A","geom":"2","score":2}],[{"indicator":"B","geom":"1","score":3},{"indicator":"B","geom":"2","score":4}]];

const result = [...[].concat(...data).reduce((map, o) => {
  const item = map.get(o.geom) || { geom: o.geom, indicator: [], score: [] }; // get the item from the map, or create a new one
  
  item.indicator.push(o.indicator);
  item.score.push(o.score);
  
  return map.set(o.geom, item); // set the item and return the map reference
}, new Map).values()]; // get the map values iterator, and use spread (...) to get an array

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Brilliantly done. However, in order to apply this to my full dataset, I would need to "un-nest" each indicator objects that are in separate containers. I'm unsuccessfully struggling with `concat` `push` `reduce` to do that. Any idea? Cheers, O.

Comment: Basically, `data.length` will return the number of indicators (2 in the sample), and `data[0].length`will return the number of geometries (2 again, but over 3000 in my full json response). I don't think there is a class for these objects (?). The data is rendered by this API request : `if (sources != null) {fetch(`${ api }/${ obj }`) .then(response => response.json()) .then(jsonresponse => { datastore.push(jsonresponse.data); this.setState({ scores: datastore });})` (sorry for ugly code chunk)

Comment: You'll have to give more a more detailed and thorough explanation of  the problem :) What is difference between my result, and your expected result, for example.

Comment: The result is perfect, however my data var is different : I have an array of objects. I realise the sample in my initial post is incorrect, it should be `let data = [[ {...},{...} ], [ {...},{...} ]];`. Sorry for the confusion :S) So to apply your code, I would need to do some sort on concatenation?

Comment: @Lecram - I've updated the answer to work with nested arrays - `[].concat(...data)`.